# How to remove disabled AD users from Get-MailboxPermission PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export

I am currently exporting all Shared Mailbox access from Exchange Online.
It worked but there are a lot of disabled users in that export.

This is where the problem begins. Even though we use Azure AD sync, the users that are disabled in our AD, are still marked as active in O365. So using a filter was not an option.

I tried exporting the Active AD Users' UPN to a CSV, then exporting my shared mailboxes too, importing the CSV's and comparing them using Compare-Object but I could not get that right either.
I also tried comparing and removing the entries that were not indicated as "==" in the arrays but I could not figure out how to do that.

Is there another way to filter on Active AD users within the Get-MailboxPermission cmdlet?

```
#Get All AD Users 
$ActiveADUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where {$_.Enabled -eq $True -and $_.userPrincipalName -like '*domain.com'} | Select @{expression={$_.userPrincipalName}; label='User'} `
| Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path "C:\activeadusers.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation

#Multiple Shared Mailboxes
$SharedMailboxes = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -Resultsize unlimited -Filter {(Name -like "DOMAIN*")}
$Results = foreach ($SharedMailbox in $SharedMailboxes)
{
Get-MailboxPermission $SharedMailbox `
| Select-Object @{expression={$_.Identity}; label='Shared Mailbox'},@{Name='Name';expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user.tostring()).displayname}},User,AccessRights `
| Where-Object {($_.user -like '*@*')}
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path "C:\sharedmailbox-access.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

This gets me the files I need, then I tried incorporating this code into the code above but the columns do not correspond and the inactive users are still in it:

```
$file1 = Import-Csv C:\sharedmailbox-access.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv C:\activeadusers.csv


$compareParams = @{
    ReferenceObject = $file1
    DifferenceObject = $file2
}

Compare-Object @compareParams -Property userPrincipalName -PassThru -IncludeEqual | 
Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -eq '==' |
 select @{expression={$_.Identity}; label='Shared Mailbox'},@{Name='Name';expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user.tostring()).displayname}},User,AccessRights |
 Export-Csv -Path 'C:\newfile.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force``
```

Comment: You have renamed `UserPrincipalName` into `User` for the  `$ActiveADUsers` array, but your Compare-Object still uses property userPrincipalName

Answer (score 0):

in your `Compare-Object` command, you tell it to use the `userPrincipalName` property, but neither of the `$ActiveADUsers` or `$SharedMailboxes` objects have that property (use `User` instead).

Because the `userPrincipalName` is null for both objects, the comparison is always true.

---

Note that you could move the `Where` clause directly into the AD command's `-Filter` for slightly increased efficiency:

```
$ActiveADUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True -and userPrincipalName -like "*domain.com"' | 
  Select @{expression={$_.userPrincipalName}; label='User'}
```